# Light paths for different Render layers

Tags: rendering, layers

I have several Render layers in my animation. I need to change value Light paths Max: 25 only for one Render layer, otherwise layer with hair looks bad. But when I change this value, it changes on all layers. I don't want to set such high value for all layers because this will increase rendering time. How to set different Light paths for different Render layers? Or is it impossible to do in one scene?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using 2 scenes clone of each other with different render settings and combine them in Compositor?

Comment: To be honest, I just found out today that can create several scenes. Yes, I tried to do it now & it worked. Hooray! Thanks for advice. And as I understand it, there is no other method, right? And by the way, which version of new scene is better to use: Link objects or Full copy? I just don't quite understand difference between them.

Comment: If you do a linked copy, any change you make to your objects will be passed on to the other linked scenes. However in a full copy, you can freely edit your objects without affecting the other scenes

Comment: Now I understood. Thanks a lot!